# How to save Google bar chart as image without using getImageURI() since this is not available with 'packages': ['bar']

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I would like to be able to generate a PNG from the SVG that is generated from the google chart.

Is there a way to do this?  I have googled and googled and can't seem to find a solution.

```js
 google.load('visualization', '1.1', {
    'packages': ['bar']
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);

function drawStuff() {
  

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', '');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Current Market Value of Assets');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Retiree Liability');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Terminated Liability');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Active Liability');
    
    data.addRows([
     

         ['2002', 51218291670, 26058500850, 5719088388, 8266522958],
         ['2008', 51218291670, 26058500850, 5719088388, 8266522958]
        
    ]);

    // Set chart options
    var options = {
        isStacked: true,
        
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        chart: {
            title: 'Year-by-year Plan Asset / Liability',
            subtitle: ''
        },
        vAxis: {
            viewWindow: {
                min: 0
            }
        },
        series: {
            1: {
              color: '#b72f2f',
                targetAxisIndex: 1
            },
            2: {
                color: 'red',
                targetAxisIndex: 1
            },
            3: {
                color: '#ff7777',
                targetAxisIndex: 1
            }
        }
    };

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
};

Here is the html needed to test with
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/jsapi?dummy=.js"></script>
<div style="margin-top: 80px; border:1px solid #cccccc; border-radius:10px; padding:20px;" id="chart_div"></div>
```

I am looking for any recommendations.